# Two 1 - N relations in Mongoid (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, database-relations

**The scenario is:**

How can an Account give ratings to another account?   This results in two lists on the Account.   Those who I have rated and those who have rated me.  (my_ratings and ratings_given)

**This boils down to:**

How can multiple 1 - N relationsips to the same entity work in Mongoid?

[In Mongoid's Docs](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/referenced/1-n.html) it says you can use `has_many` and `belongs_to` to link the entities together.

I currently have this on **Account**

```
  has_many :ratings, :as => "my_ratings"
  has_many :ratings, :as => "ratings_given"
```

and this on **Ratings**:

```
 belongs_to :user, :as => 'Rater'
 belongs_to :user, :as => 'Ratie'
```

The docs don't cover this case, so I thought you would have to differentiate between the two with an :as parameter.

Is this even remoting correct?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using the class_name and inverse_of options:

```
class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  has_many :ratings_given, :class_name => 'Ratings', :inverse_of => :rater
  has_many :my_ratings, :class_name => 'Ratings', :inverse_of => :ratee
end

class Ratings
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  belongs_to :rater, :class_name => 'Account', :inverse_of => :ratings_given
  belongs_to :ratee, :class_name => 'Account', :inverse_of => :my_ratings
end
```

The documentation has changed since I was last working with it so I wasn't sure whether this is still the recommended approach. Looks like it doesn't mention these options on the [1-many referenced page](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/referenced/1-n.html). But if you take a look at the general page on [relations](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many) they are covered there.

In any case you need to explicitly link ratings_given/rater and my_ratings/ratee associations when there are two associations to the same class, otherwise mongoid has no way to know which of the two potential inverses to pick.

Comment: It's important to note that when you have multiple relationships, all must get an :inverse_of declaration, on both sides. Otherwise mongoid gets confused.